# How we can increase size of 2d vector in Java?

Tags: java, vector, 2d-vector

Assume we defined a `2d vector` in Java. Size of the first dimension is `10` and size of second dimension is `1`. Now if we want to increase size of first dimension of this `2d vector` what should we do?

Assume we want add number `1` to 30th cell (i.e. `v1[29][0]=1`), but our vector size is `10`.

Here is my code in Java:

```
Vector [][] v1 = new Vector [10][];

for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
    if (i==0) {
        v1[i]=new Vector[1];
    }
    else
        v1[i]=v1[0];
v1[0][0]=new Vector(1);
```

Comment: Perhaps an implementation of `java.util.List`?

Comment: Unless you are required to use arrays I would suggest to use `List<List<YourType>>`. As implementation you could use [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). Btw, if your second dimension is always `1` then a simple 1d array will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for comments, but I did not get a good answer,yet.

Comment: You misunderstand what you are doing. This code actually creates a 3-dimensional data structure: an array containing arrays, each containing Vectors. Arrays are different from Vectors in Java. I suggest you read up on the difference between Arrays and Vectors before attempting to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new, bigger array, for example `v1 = new Vector[30][]`.

Note that `Vector` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

Also, make sure that you understand what are you doing. If you only need to "add number 1 to 30th cell (i.e. v1[30][0]=1)", then `int v1 = new int[31][]` should be enough, without any vectors. By the way, 30th cell is `v1[29][0]`, not `v1[30][0]`, watch out for this common mistake-by-one.